# Submitting an html form with python, to update a Mysqldb record does not work properly

Tags: python, html, mysql, forms, bottle

I am trying to submit an html form to update a record in my mysql database.My code is in python, and I have tried everything including form.FieldStorage(),POST and GET methods but nothing is succesfull .
My python code is the following

```
@route('/update_artist_information/:numb', method='GET')
def update_artist_information(numb):

    if request.GET.get('Update Information','').strip():
        val1= request.GET.get('val1', '').strip()
        val2 = request.GET.get('val2', '').strip()
        val3 = request.GET.get('val3', '0').strip()

        conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='username', passwd='mypass', db='mydb')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SET NAMES utf8")
        query = "UPDATE tab1 SET val1 = '%s', val2 = '%s',  val3 =%s WHERE ar_taut = '%s'" % (val1,val2,val3,numb)
        c.execute(query)
        conn.commit()
        c.close()

        return artists_show_all()

    else:
        conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='username', passwd='mypass', db='mydb')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SET NAMES utf8")
        query = "SELECT val1, val2, val3 FROM tab1 WHERE numb = '%s'" %numb
        c.execute(query)
        cur_data = c.fetchone()
        print (cur_data)
        return template('Update_Artist_Information.html', old = cur_data, numb = numb)
```

My html file is the following

```
<p><strong>Update Artist Information </strong></p>

<form action="/artists_show_all/{{numb}}"method="GET">
<table width="239" height="147" border="1">
<tr>
    <td width="83">val1</td>
    <td width="140"><input type="text" name="val1" id="val1" value="    {{old[0]}}" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>val2</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="val2" id="val2" value="{{old[1]}}"/>    </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Birth Year</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="val3" id="val3" value="{{old[2]}}"   /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Update Information" id="Update  Information" value="Update Information" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</form>
```

And the error I get after trying to update is "This page does not exist!".I have checked every single route in all my files and I cannot find anything wrong.I am new to web applications aand python so please if you can help me I would appreciate it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What library are you using for your server?

Comment: this are all the libraries I am importing:                                              import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
import cgi
import cgitb
                                                                                                                  from bottle import route, run, debug, template, request, error

Comment: Try `route('/update_artist_information/<numb>`

Comment: It is not working..I am still getting the error that the page does not exist.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8080/update_artist_information/3 gives me a working page with your code after I remove the database stuff. Can you include more details such as the URL you are accessing and when exactly you get the error?

Comment: @AlexHall Well I have a search form at @route('/presentation_of_artists') which leads me to a search result form at  @route('/view_artist_results').The result form has a an edit button which leads me to the @route('/update_artist_information/<numb>).So I have a python function which returns an output at @route('/view_artist_results') after I have updated the information by clicking the Update button.But after clicking the Update button I get a the page does not exist" error

Comment: Copy the URL where the error is shown.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8080/artists_show_all/P214214?Name=%CE%93%CE%99%CE%91%CE%9D%CE%9D%CE%97%CE%A3&Surname=%CE%91%CE%93%CE%93%CE%95%CE%9B%CE%91%CE%9A%CE%91%CE%A312&Birth+Year=1951&Update+Information=Update+Information

Comment: So do you have a function with `@route('/artists_show_all/:numb')`?

Comment: @route('/artists_show_all/:numb')
def artists_show_all():
    

    conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='username', passwd='mypass', db='mydb')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SET NAMES utf8")
    c.execute("select * from tab1")
    result = c.fetchall()
    c.close()

    output = template('View_Artist_Results.html', rows=result)
    return output

Comment: There's no `numb` argument in that function.

Comment: Yeah you're right.I tried changed the route to @route('/artists_show_all/') in both the html file and the def route and it is still not workig though.I will try to rewrite the function and check again all my files for any flaws ..

Comment: Make a copy of the project and delete as much as you can to narrow down the problem. For example the database is not relevant to the problem, just hardcode values. If you still can't find it then post the full code and we can actually run it and see for ourselves.

Comment: Ok, thank you !! I will inform you if there is any update !